# @Index annotation in SDN4

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Why there is an @Index annotation in SDN4 if it does not manage Neo4j indexes anymore? In SDN3 it was used to populate indexes in the database, but now, taking into account the documentation, it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be there any more- it isn't used and will be removed.