# Spring-data-neo4j v4, why no index

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

According to the [migration of SDN (Spring-data-neo4j) v3 to SDN4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#migration), Indexes are not present anymore, so this is not foreseen to work anymore.

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends Unversioned{
    @Indexed(unique=true,failOnDuplicate = true) // <-- THIS
    private String login;
    ...
}
```

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637661/index-annotation-in-sdn4) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637661/index-annotation-in-sdn4), no-one seems surprised. Isn't that the "point" to have constraints defined on the model itself ?

The mission defined on the main page of [Sring-data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/):

> Spring Data’s mission is to provide a familiar and **consistent**, Spring-based programming model for data access while still retaining the special traits of the underlying data store.

Even when comparing to [the latest Spring-data-JPA official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/com/oreilly/springdata/jpa/core/Customer.java), constraints are still defined on the model:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

    private String firstname, lastname;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private EmailAddress emailAddress;
```

Allowing constraints to be defined on the very java-based-model seemed to me to be the less error-prone system. 
How are we supposed to build a model consistent if the model & constraints are decoupled ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give you an answer "from the trenches". I used SDN 3.x quite a lot, now I use 4.x, I also use spring data mongo, which has `@Indexed` annotation.

I agree it is very convenient when you just want to create an index on a property.

But there are several problems in the long run. When the application is deployed and maintained I had to resort to managing indexes in code, not declaratively.

These include

- renaming the property, won't delete the old index
- changing the index (e.g. making it unique constraint)
- these annotation usually don't provide all the possibilities of the native database index definition
- class hierarchies - what if you have an `@Indexed` on a property in a base class - what index(es) are created? Just for the base class label? (or collection in mongo), all children...?

In the end you trade one line with `@Indexed` annotation for another

```
@Autowired
private Neo4jOperations operations;

@PostConstruct
public void createIndexesAndConstraints() {
    ...
    operations.query("CREATE INDEX ON :Person(email)", EMPTY_MAP);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of SDN 4, index management is considered to be out of scope for the mapping framework, and it is recommended that they be managed outside of Spring.

More info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_indexing

Comment: But I don't get why such a drastic design change. How is the man of the street supposed to define his constraints then ? The java-based definition seemed to be the best place, no refactoring issues, one consistent bean definition (to rule them all)

Comment: You can still define them by executing cypher via the Neo4jTemplate or Session. The decision was taken because index management was no longer considered to be the responsibility of a mapping framework.

Comment: That's the point, if say the variable name changes, the the index in a separate file also needs to be changed. This is a regression to everything that has been accomplished so far... Constraints are so important, that's the only fence to loosing data, esp. in a neo4j context where merges are dominant. I wouldn't want to upgrade to such a decoupled model. Thanks for your answer